# Allow user to configure Tampermonkey @match value for domain, without editing the script

Tags: tampermonkey

I'd like to make a Tampermonkey script that's currently in a secret gist publicly available. However, the script needs to be restricted to run within a particular site of interest to the user, but the domain name cannot be known in advance. And leaving in the domain name I'm currently using means I can't make the gist public. But taking it out means any users who want to use the script have to manually edit the @match header for their use case.

Are there any good patterns for this? I'm reluctant to make the script run on just any site. Anyone considering a Tampermonkey script who sees that it does not have a @match (or @include) header is less likely to even review the code to see if it is useful.

Comment: Users can add their custom match patterns for a script in its settings in all major managers like Tampermonkey, Greasemonkey, Violentmonkey and possibly others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no user friendly API for parametrizing userscripts. Your users simple need to replace the domain name. For making your script public, just use `www.example.net` which is a designated example domain.

If you want to help your users altering the domain, the best way would be to make a website for it (easily on github pages from the script's repository). Then write a simple JS code that produces script based on what domain the user enters in some form.

Comment: Yeah, that’s what I was afraid of. Using example.com won’t work because then I can’t use the auto update feature of Tampermonkey or I have to host and update two versions, private and public.